# How do I compare one row to the next?

Tags: r

I want to be able to compare values of 2 variables of over 30 variables. 
Example data would look like this :

```
A, B
0, 2014-05-01 13
30, 2014-05-02 14
30, 2014-05-02 15
60, 2014-05-02 15
30, 2014-05-03 08
60, 2014-05-03 09
```

A is a number. 
B is the timestamp in the format - %Y-%m-%d %H . 
Now, I would like to extract the rows in which the date from one row to the next is the same. And, the hour is within one hour of the row above. (So, for row i if the date is 14th may and 9 am. And row i + 1 the date is 14th may and hour be 8 or 9 or 10. Then, it will be pulled out in a separate data frame, rbinding each row that satisfies the condition.

Running it on the above data, result will be

```
30, 2014-05-02 15
60, 2014-05-02 15
60, 2014-05-03 09
```

Comment: Please feel free to edit the question if it helps improve clarity. Thanks

Comment: So what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Pulled out to a separate data.frame how? One for each block? Or just one data.frame?

Comment: Added the row to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `lubridate`:

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(0,30,30,60,30,60), B =  
c("2014-05-01 13","2014-05-02 14","2014-05-02 15","2014-05-02 15","2014-05-03 08","2014-05-03 09"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

You can use `lag` to pull out the previous value of `B`, and use `dhours` to advance it by one hour:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(B = ymd_h(B),
         close = B <= lag(B + dhours(1))) %>%
  filter(close)

A                   B close
1 30 2014-05-02 15:00:00  TRUE
2 60 2014-05-02 15:00:00  TRUE
3 60 2014-05-03 09:00:00  TRUE
```

Comment: I wonder how Hadley realizes the need for such functions. Is there a package from another language that he draws inspirations from?

Comment: @Vlo Perhaps he uses dark arts! Though I often wonder if useRs find applications that he and his fellow-developers never quite imagined..